# Appending an empty list to a numpy array changes its dtype

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of integers. In my code I need to append some other integers from a list, which works fine and gives me back an array of dtype `int64` as expected. But it may happen that the list of integers to append is empty. In that case, numpy returns an array of `float64` values. Exemplary code below:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10, dtype='int64')

np.append(a, [10])  # dtype is int64
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

np.append(a, [])    # dtype is float64
# array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

Is this expected behaviour? If so, what is the rationale behind this? Could this even be a bug?

The documentation for `np.append` states that the return value is

> A copy of `arr` with `values` appended to `axis`.

Since there are no values to append, shouldn't it just return a copy of the array?

(Numpy version: 1.22.4, Python version: 3.8.0)

Comment: Ultimately `concatenate` is not joining lists.  It is joining arrays.  If one or more of the arguments is a list, it is first converted into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `dtype` for a numpy array constructed from an empty list is `float64`:

```
>>> np.array([])
array([], dtype=float64)
```

A `float64` dtype will "win" over the `int64` dtype and promote everything to `float64`, because converting the other way around would cause loss of precision (i.e. truncate any `float64`). Of course this is an extreme case because there is no value to truncate in an empty array, but the check is only done on the `dtype`. More info on this is in [the doc for `numpy.result_type()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html).

In fact:

```
>>> a = np.array(dtype='int64')
>>> a
array([], dtype=int64)

>>> b = np.array([])
>>> b
array([], dtype=float64)

>>> np.result_type(a, b)
dtype('float64')
```

The [`np.promote_types()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html#numpy.promote_types) function is used to determine the type to promote to:

```
>>> np.promote_types('int64', 'float64')
dtype('float64')
```

See also: [How the dtype of numpy array is calculated internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55181559/3889449)

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your array when appending and specify the type you want:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10, dtype="int64")
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64)

np.append(a, [])
array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.], dtype=float64)

np.append(a, np.array([], dtype=a.dtype))
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the source code for `numpy.append`, we can see that it calls `numpy.concatenate`. Looking at the documentation for this method, we see that it accepts two type-related arguments: `dtype` and `casting`, the default of which is None. Since `numpy.append` does not provide values for either of these, the defaults are assumed. The default for `casting` is `same-kind`, which allows for safe casting within a kind, as described [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html). Since all of this is done in C, my guess is that `concatenate` tried to guess the type of the array you provided. Since it was empty, however, no type could be assumed so it took the widest possible type that would fit both inputs and assigned that to the output.

If you want to avoid this, you should probably append using numpy arrays instead of Python lists:

```
np.append(a, np.array([], dtype = 'int64'))
```

Comment: `np.array([])` is float dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I saw that in Marco Bonelli's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you avoid appending the the empty list with some sort of if statement?

I think its expected behaviour as [] is still a value that gets appended. Obviously [] can't be an integer so it probably assumes its a float (default casting).

Comment: Yes, that's what I did now. Default casting makes sense, but I still think it's kind of counter-intuitive. Since nothing is appended, it should not change the original array, right?

Comment: I disagree with the review.  This does provide an answer, just as good as the others.  It is appending an array with shape (0,).  That is not nothing.  If I concatenate lists, `[1,2,3]+[]`, the result is `[1,2,3]`, but it isn't handled as a special case.